# How can I link functions in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, function, typescript, commonjs

I'm new to programming and I'm re-writing a node package created by a friend of mine. The package is written in JavaScript and I want to convert it to TypeScript:

There are several commonjs modules, most of them are just functions, e.g.:

```js
/* foo.js (original)*/
exports.foo = function foo(values) {
  //some code
}

/* foo.ts */
export function foo(values: number[]): number {
  //some code
} 

// which is compiled to foo.js (new)
function foo(values) {
  //some code
}
exports.foo = foo;
```

He created a link to the `foo` function: `exports.bar = exports.foo`

I want to keep the old function (`foo`) and link it to `bar`, and be able to use the new function as `bar(values)`, how can I do it?

I thought I could do something like:

```
export var bar: (values) => number = foo;
```

But for some reason is not working.

Comment: What does it do? What error are you getting?

Comment: I was having `cannot invoke a function whose type lacks a call signature`, but it seems I had a mistake importing another file. Now is working